# How to match two lists by the condition if they may not be composed correctly with one element difference

Tags: python, list, sequence

I have code that should return true if all the elements in the lists are the same (order is not important) or if they may not be composed correctly with one element difference.

```
def check(list1, list2):
    s = set(list1)
    c = sum(1 for v in list2 if v in s)
    return c == len(list2) - 1
```

But this code does not work correctly if the lists have the same elements. And it returns false instead of true.

For example, there are the following lists:

```
l1 = ["abc3", "abc3", "abc3"]
l2 = ["word1", "abc3", "list"]
```

The result of comparing the two lists (l1, l2) should return False, because the elements of list l2 are repeated once in list l1

```
l3 = ["abc3", "word1", "zzzzzz"]
l4 = ["word1", "abc3", "list"]
```

The result of comparing the two lists(l3, l4) should return True, because the elements of list l4 are repeated twice in list l3.

```
l5 = ["word1", "zzzz", "z"]
l6 = ["word1", "abc3", "list"]
```

The result of comparing the two lists(l5, l6) should return False, because the elements of list l6 are repeated once in list l5, and two elements do not match

```
l6 = ['1', '2', '1']
l7 = ['2', '2', '2']
```

The result of comparing the two lists(l6, l7) should return False, because the elements of list l7 are repeated three times in list l6.

If the lists are the same, the result is True, because the lists match.

```
l7 = ["1", "word"]
l8 = ["word", "1"]
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic of the various comparisons.  For instance, you say "the two lists(l3, l4) should return True, because the elements of list l4 are repeated twice in list l3".  But, not all elements in l4 are even in l3 and none are repeated twice.  For instance, "list" from l4 is not in l3.

Comment: Two lists can differ by only one item. For example l3 = ["abc3", "word1", "zzzzzz"]
l4 = ["word1", "abc3", "list"] --> "abc3" in l3 and in l4, "word1" in l3 and l4, but "zzzzzz" not in l4 and "list" not in l3. If the lists were like this l3 = ["abc3", "1", "zzzzzz"] and l4 = ["word1", "abc3", "list"]  the result would be False, because "1", "zzzzzz" not in l4 and "word1", "list" not in l3

Comment: I was thinking of making a counter that returns false if two or more do not match, but I don't know how to implement

Comment: Are the lists always the same length? Are they always of length 3?

Comment: yeah, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, the following satisfies your test cases by:

- Using collections.counter to count word frequencies
- Checks if there is only a difference in one in the set of words used by the two lists
- Checks that word frequencies are the same for the common words between the two lists

**Code**

```
from collections import Counter

def check(list1, list2):
    c1 = Counter(list1)
    c2 = Counter(list2)
    
    s1 = set(c1.keys())
    s2 = set(c2.keys())
    
    # At most one difference in elements
    if len(s1 - s2) > 1 or len(s2 - s1) > 1:
        return False
    
    # Must have the same frequency for elements in common
    common = s1 & s2
    return [c1[c] for c in common] == [c2[c] for c in common]
```

**Tests**

```
l1 = ["abc3", "abc3", "abc3"]
l2 = ["word1", "abc3", "list"]
print(check(l1, l2))               # Output: False

l3 = ["abc3", "word1", "zzzzzz"]
l4 = ["word1", "abc3", "list"]
print(check(l3, l4))              # Output: True

l5 = ["word1", "zzzz", "z"]
l6 = ["word1", "abc3", "list"]
print(check(l5, l6))              # Output: False

l6 = ['1', '2', '1']
l7 = ['2', '2', '2']
print(check(l6, l7))              # Output: False

l7 = ["1", "word"]
l8 = ["word", "1"]
print(check(l7, l8))              # Output: True

l9 = [1, 2, 1]
l10 = [1, 1, 4]
print(check(l9, l10))             # Output: True
```